# NSString compare special character independent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstring

How can I compare two NSString, character independent?

`NSPredicate` offers the `==[d]` comparator.
However I didn't find a method for comparing two `NSString`s directly.

---

For exapmle, those two string should be considered as identical:

> Šämplé Štrïñg
>
> Sample String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *s1 = @"Šämplé Štrïñg";
NSString *s2 = @"Sample String";
NSComparisonResult cmp = [s1 compare:s2 options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch];
// --> cmp = NSOrderedSame
```

Comment: Cool, how can you do this with `contains:`?

Comment: You can use `rangeOfString:options:` with the `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch` option.

Answer (score 3):

Use `compare:options:`:

```
NSString *str1 = ...;
NSString *str2 = ...;
NSComparisonResult result = [str1 compare:str2 options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSWidthInsensitiveSearch];
```

If you want to do other actions with the strings, you can fold both strings to their simpler forms:

```
NSString *fold1 = [str1 stringByFoldingWithOptions:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSWidthInsensitiveSearch locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSString *fold2 = [str2 stringByFoldingWithOptions:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSWidthInsensitiveSearch locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSRange range = [fold1 rangeOfString:fold2]; // or other string comparisons
```

Comment: Great answer, but **Martin R** was faster ;)